# How can I add credentials for the enable password level of access to Cisco routers for openvas?

Tags: openvas

I just started playing with the OpenVAS virtual appliance.

So I added credentials for ssh which will be used to access Cisco routers:
[image]

So this will let OpenVAS login to user mode, but how will it access enable mode? Or am I going about this the wrong way? I was thinking OpenVAS would need enable mode access to do certain scans.

Answer (score 0):

No, OpenVAS should not be SSHing into anything.

The point of a vulnerability scan is to examine the public-facing (either internet-public or internal-LAN-public) interface of your systems and applications.

If vulnerability scanners were able to SSH into servers, network gear, etc., *everything* would have vulnerabilities.

Comment: Hmm ok, but how will it do OVAL scans? Won't it need access to the routers config and stuff for OVAL? The main reason I'm using it is to validate my routers against OVAL definitions

Comment: This answer is incorrect. OpenVAS also provides the ability to log into devices and perform local scans (e.g. to determine the specific version of software installed).